# Issue After migrating from version 1.7.2 to 2.1.6

Tags: magento-1.7

Previous Version: 1.7.2
Current Version: 2.1.6

After migrating magento version from 1.7.2 to 2.1.6, following issues are coming.
Don't know, Whats the problem. Please help me to sort out this problem.
[image]

-----------XXXXXXXXXX_______________XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete the "di" folder located in var directory.

2.Run this command in project root folder command:cd /yourmagentoroot/bin

3.Then run this command sudo ./magento setup:di:compile

4.Finally, give file/directory permissions.

I have Written Detailed blog for this problem at blog.trimantra.com ,

Please follow below URL for more detail

http://blog.trimantra.com/error-magento-2-upgrade-command/